# How can we open show date picker according to Central European Standard Time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datepicker

In a flutter, I want to show the date picker according to Central European Standard Time. How can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
DateTime? newDate = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(1900),
          lastDate: DateTime(2040),
          helpText: 'Select Date',
          cancelText: "CANCEL",
          confirmText: "SAVE",
          initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
          selectableDayPredicate: _decideWhichDayToEnable,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: colorPrimary, // button text color
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: child!,
            );
          },
        ).then((value) {
          if (value != null) {
            setState(() {
              date = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(value);
              isDateSelected = true;
              _affiliateReward.currentState!.refreshData();
            });
          }
          return null;
        });
        if (newDate == null) return;
        setState(() {
          dateFrom = newDate;
        });
```

So, the above code is used to select the date for transaction. but Central European Standard time. How can we change that in flutter?

```
bool _decideWhichDayToEnable(DateTime day) {
    if ((day.isAfter(DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 36500))) &&
        day.isBefore(DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 0))))) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is not really `showDatePicker` related but rather `DateTime`. Inside your `showDatePicker` you can set the `initialDate` (you use `DateTime.now()` thats why the timezone of you system devices gets used unless it is not anchored to UTC).

Since basic flutter `DateTime` only supports local or UTC time you need to convert the selected timestamp to CET.

There are probably two approaches you could choose from:

1. Use a package with timezone support like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone).
   You can then convert the selected timestamp into your desired timezone. This probably makes sense if you do a lot of different timezone related operations.
2. Do the timezone conversion by yourself:
   You can take the selected value from your `showDatePicker` - make sure that it is UTC with `value.toUtc()` and add/subtract the specific time to convert into your desired timezone. For instance:

   ```
   if (value != null) {
      setState(() {
         const utc = value.toUtc();
         // Central Europe Standard Time is UTC + 01:00
         var cetTimeStamp = utc.add(Duration(hours: 1)));
         // do whatever you need
      });
   }
   ```

Since flutter `datetime` only supports local time and UTC you do not explicitly know that this timestamp is CET. From an engineering point of view this is a quite unclean. Also if you send this object anywhere the timezone is still UTC. You can ofcourse also get the `DateTime` as string and add the timezone to that string. How ever in such cases I'd recommened to use a third party package as I mentioned above.